# Hide Unix Shell Script Backgrounded Process Output

Tags: linux, unix

What is the best approach to hide a backgrounded processes output from the command line screen?  I have the below script that backgrounds start.jar which is a web server.  Any ideas?

**Unix Shell Script:**

```
cd examples/appserver
java -jar start.jar &
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `/dev/null`, the output sink, is for.

```
java -jar start.jar > /dev/null &
```

Comment: don't forget `java -jar start.jar > /dev/null 2>&1 &` to dump standard error too

Comment: jwodder's solution still let the startup of the web server output come to the console. When I added evil otto's it blocks it all, thanks!

Comment: shortcut for @evilotto's solution is java -jar start.jar &>/dev/null &